# How to allow the user to enter a value from the menu and return an output?

Tags: java, oop, syntax-error

I have tried to create a menu from which a user can input a value and receive the information of a particular child which was created as an object of the Child class. The information of a child is outputted due to the personality chosen by the user. This personality will be paired with the different children.  I'm unsure of how to correct my code and I am struggling to correct where I have gone wrong.

```
public class ChildTestDrive

 {
   
public static void main(String[] args)
  
{
   
System.out.println( "Welcome to the Child Vending MACHINE");
   System.out.println( "What personailty do you want your child to have?");
   System.out.println( " ");
   System.out.println( "MENU");
   System.out.println( "1 - Melancholy");
   System.out.println( "2 - Scared");
   System.out.println( "3 - Cheerful");
   System.out.println( "4 - Sleep");
   System.out.println( "5 - Hungry");
   System.out.println( "0 - Exit Menu");
   System.out.println( " ");
   
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter a number from the menu: ");
   personality = input.nextInt();

   if (personality == 1) {
       System.out.println("Congratulations you are now the parent of : ", one.name, " who is ", one.age, " years old. ");
       one.cry()
   }
   else if (personality ==2){
       System.out.println("Congratulations you are now the parent of : ", two.name, " who is ", two.age, " years old. ");
       two.scream()
   }
   else if (personality==3){
       System.out.println("Congratulations you are now the parent of : ", three.name, " who is ", three.age, " years old. ");
       three.giggles()
   }
   else if (personality==4){
       System.out.println("Congratulations you are now the parent of : ", four.name, " who is ", four.age, " years old. ");
       four.yawn()
   }
   else if (personality==5){
       System.out.println("Congratulations you are now the parent of : ", five.name, " who is ", five.age, " years old. ");
       five.cry()
   }
   else if (personality==0){
       System.out.printld("GoodBye!")
   }
   Child one = new Child();
   one.name = "Timmy";
   one.gender = "male";
   one.age = 1;
   one.cry();
    
   Child two = new Child();
   two.name = "Taylor";
   two.gender = "female";
   two.age = 2;
   two.scream();
    
   Child three = new Child();
   three.name = "Joey";
   three.gender = "male";
   three.age = 3;
   three.giggles();
    
   Child four = new Child();
   four.name = "Cleo";
   four.gender = "female";
   four.age = 4;
   four.yawn();
   
   Child five = new Child();
   five.name = "Guilleme";
   five.gender = "male";
   five.age = 2;
   five.hungry();
  }
}
class Child
{
 String name;
 String gender;
 int age;
 
  void cry()
 {
   System.out.println("WAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!");
 }
  void scream()
 {
   System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHH!");
 }
  void giggles()
 {
   System.out.println("teeheehee");
 }
  void yawn()
 {
   System.out.println("*yawns*");
 }
  void hungry()
 {
   System.out.println("pizzapizzapizzapizzapizzapizzapizzapizzapizza");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing classes **before** they are instantiated. Example, you reference an instance of the `Child` class i.e. `one.cry()` before its been been created in.

```
  System.out.println("Congratulations you are now the parent of : ", one.name, " who is ", one.age, " years old. ");
  one.cry();
```

it needs to be **after** the following code:

```
Child one = new Child();
one.name = "Timmy";
one.gender = "male";
one.age = 1;
one.cry();
```

Just move your instantiation of the `Child` classes above these lines and add semi-colons `(;)` after you call the `child` methods() to it. There were also a few other things I needed to fix so that your code should at least compile.

---

### See your fixed code below

```
import java.util.*;

public class ChildTestDrive {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Child one = new Child();
    one.name = "Timmy";
    one.gender = "male";
    one.age = 1;

    Child two = new Child();
    two.name = "Taylor";
    two.gender = "female";
    two.age = 2;

    Child three = new Child();
    three.name = "Joey";
    three.gender = "male";
    three.age = 3;

    Child four = new Child();
    four.name = "Cleo";
    four.gender = "female";
    four.age = 4;

    Child five = new Child();
    five.name = "Guilleme";
    five.gender = "male";
    five.age = 2;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Child Vending MACHINE");
    System.out.println("What personailty do you want your child to have?");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("MENU");
    System.out.println("1 - Melancholy");
    System.out.println("2 - Scared");
    System.out.println("3 - Cheerful");
    System.out.println("4 - Sleep");
    System.out.println("5 - Hungry");
    System.out.println("0 - Exit Menu");
    System.out.println(" ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number from the menu: ");
    int personality;
    personality = input.nextInt();

    if (personality == 1) {
      System.out.println("Congratulations you are now the parent of : " + one.name + " who is " + one.age + " years old. ");
      one.cry();
    } else if (personality == 2) {
      System.out.println("Congratulations you are now the parent of : " + two.name + " who is " + two.age + " years old. ");
      two.scream();
    } else if (personality == 3) {
      System.out.println("Congratulations you are now the parent of : " + three.name + " who is " + three.age + " years old. ");
      three.giggles();
    } else if (personality == 4) {
      System.out.println("Congratulations you are now the parent of : " + four.name + " who is " + four.age + " years old. ");
      four.yawn();
    } else if (personality == 5) {
      System.out.println("Congratulations you are now the parent of : " + five.name + " who is " + five.age + " years old. ");
      five.cry();
    } else if (personality == 0) {
      System.out.println("GoodBye!");
    }
  }
}

class Child {
  String name;
  String gender;
  int age;

  void cry() {
    System.out.println("WAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!");
  }
  void scream() {
    System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHH!");
  }
  void giggles() {
    System.out.println("teeheehee");
  }
  void yawn() {
    System.out.println("*yawns*");
  }
  void hungry() {
    System.out.println("pizzapizzapizzapizzapizzapizzapizzapizzapizza");
  }
}
```

Comment: Just got home and ran that through a compiler. Made a couple of changes and seems to run fine now.